# Copying data which less than 100 times repeated in column - Excel-VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Having very huge excel data. I want to copy the data from column C to other sheet with condition. C column having n number of text values want to take only which word contains less than 100 times repeatedly.

```
Sub DelR() 

    Dim myRow As Range 
    Dim to Delete As Range 
    For I=2 to 10000 
    If workseets("Sheet1").Cells(I,2) >100 Then 
    Set myRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(I) 
    If toDelete = myRow Else 
    Set to Delete = Union(toDelete, myRow) 
    End If 
    End If 
    Next I 
    If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.EntireRow.Delete 

End Sub
```

Comment: please share the code what you have tried.you cannot expect to get the code for your problem just by asking a question. Please do your research and show what you have tried. Please have a look at this 
  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I am very new to vba coding I strucked on this point. Anyone pls help me for this.

Comment: Having very huge excel data. I want to delete the data from column C which occurred more than 100 times.

Have tried this code:

Sub DelR()
Dim myRow As Range
Dim to Delete As Range
For I=2 to 10000
      If workseets("Sheet1").Cells(I,2) >100 Then
Set myRow = Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(I)
If toDelete = myRow
Else
Set to Delete = Union(toDelete, myRow)
End If
End If
Next I
If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub

Comment: It's not deleting properly

Comment: @Ein2012 have shared the code already

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub DelR() 
    Dim sht As WorkSheet
    Dim myRow As Range 
    Dim to Delete As Range 
    Set sht = worksheets("Sheet1")
    For I=2 to 10000 
        If Application.Countif(sht.Columns(2), _
                               sht.Cells(I,2).Value) >100 Then 
            Set myRow = sht.Rows(I) 
            If toDelete Is Nothing 
                Set toDelete = myRow
            Else 
                Set toDelete = Application.Union(toDelete, myRow) 
            End If 
        End If 
    Next I 
    If Not toDelete Is Nothing Then toDelete.EntireRow.Delete 

End Sub
```

Comment: Code not working. This code not deleting the word which accounted more than 100 times.

Comment: What exact;y is in column I of your data?  I write that code based on what you posted.

Comment: I Column having data like--- CARBN01.MID, EAST.MID,CARBN01.MID,CMNTY.MID etc..  Most of the words contains more than 100 time repeatedly. I want to delete the column which contains more than 100 times displayed or need to copy which words are contains leads than 100 times to other sheet.

Comment: See my edits above - that should delete rows with values occuring > 100 times in Col B

Comment: Hi Williams, Have tried this code in original sheet which contains more than 8000 rows. But excel got hanged. So I can't use this way. Can you suggest we can use the coo and for copying the data to another sheet which contains less than 100 count.